# Firebase mostra dados em uma activity e na outra não

Tags: android

Estou usando o firebase. Para fazer um teste e de como usá-lo fiz todo o procedimento em uma activity de teste do meu app. Vi que funcionou, então quero colocá-la para a activity correta. Os códigos de ambas estão corretas, porém quando executo na activity cliente não aparece nada.

Segue os códigos:

Activity teste:

```
public class ActivityTeste extends AppCompatActivity {

Firebase objetoRef;
ListView minhaLista;

ArrayList<String> minhaListaDeTarefas = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //Setar o botão voltar
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); //Setar o botão voltar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Setar o botão voltar

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    minhaLista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewteste1);
    objetoRef = new Firebase("https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/");
    Firebase novaRef = objetoRef.child("Pessoa");

    final FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, novaRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(s);

        }
    };

      minhaLista.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Este mesmo código estou utilizando na activity certa.
E nesta não mostra os dados:

[image: Mostra o conteúdo Firebase]

[image: Não mostra o conteúdo Firebase]

Comment: Cadê o código do Actvitiy cliente?

Comment: @seamusd como falei encima, ambas estão com o mesmo código. Não tem sentido eu colocar o mesmo código duas vezes.

Comment: Renomear o que você diz cara ?

Comment: Mas não tem sentindo né cara. Isso no final dará o mesmo que eu fiz até  agora. Pegar o código da activity teste e colocar na activity correta.

Comment: Está dando algum erro ou só não aparece!?

Comment: Isso que é o estranho. Ele compila e não dá erro nenhum. Só não aparece mesmo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera ontem consegui resolver. 
O que estava acontecendo é um bug. Depois de desinstalar o app e rodar novamente ele acessou corretamente. Obrigado.